# How can I call a React-Native navigator from an outside MeteorListView file?

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-native

This may be more a javascript question than a react-native/meteor question: I am adding Meteor connectivity to an existing React Native app, and have run into a snag with navigation. I previously had a ListView that provided an onPress function each row that would call the navigation. In keeping with Meteor's createContainer protocol, I've used (in my case) a "PuzzlesContainer" in place of the ListView that, in a separate file, refers to

```
const PuzzlesContainer = ({ puzzlesReady }) => {
  return (
    <Puzzles
      puzzlesReady={puzzlesReady}
    />
  );
};
export default createContainer(() => {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('puzzles-list');
  return {
    puzzlesReady: handle.ready(),
  };
}, PuzzlesContainer);
```

This file includes the "Puzzles" file, which is also a const function that contains the MeteorListView:

```
const Puzzles = ({ puzzlesReady }) => {
  if (!puzzlesReady) {
    return null;//<Loading />;
  }else{

  return (
    <View style={launcherStyle.container}>
        <MeteorListView
            collection="puzzles"
            renderRow={
                (puzzle) =>
                <View >
                    <TouchableHighlight style={launcherStyle.launcher} onPress={()=>onSelect(puzzle.text)}>
                         <Text style={launcherStyle.text}>{puzzle.text}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
. . .
```

My problem is that there is now no context for the original routing scheme, so when I call

```
this.props.navigator.push
```

it gives "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator')". How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I liked the suggestion of globalizing my navigation, a) I never managed to do it and b) it seemed like maybe not the best practice. For anyone else who might encounter this issue, I finally succeeded by passing the navigation props in each of the JSX tags--so:

```
 <PuzzlesContainer 
    navigator={this.props.navigator} 
    id={'puzzle contents'}
 />
```

in the parent (react component) file, then

```
<Puzzles
    puzzlesReady={puzzlesReady} 
    navigator={navigator} 
    id={'puzzle contents'}
/>
```

in the second 'const' (Meteor  container) file, and using it

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>navigator.replace({id: 'puzzle launcher', ... })}>
```

in the third 'const' (MeteorListView) file. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot. You can use a "context" instead of passing props. That way you won't have pass props even when you don't need it at intermediate components.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to look at the new `NavigationExperimental`, which handles nagivator in a redux fashion.

Another method is, even though I do not know if this is recommended or not, to globalize the navigator component by assigning it to a module. It can be something like this

```
// nav.js
let nav = null

export function setNav = _nav => nav = _nav

export function getNav = () => {
  if (nav) {
    return nav
  } else {
    throw "Nav not initialized error" 
  }
}
```

Then when you first get hold of your navigator, do this

```
// component.js
import { Navigator } from 'react-native'
import { setNav } from './nav'

// ...
  renderScene={ (route, navigator) => {
    setNav(navigator)
    // render scene below
    // ...
  }}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay...I like the suggestion of globalizing the navigator, and will look further into that. My initial attempts of modifying my nav.js (which is a "class . . . extends React.Component" construct) are throwing errors--but I think you've steered me down the right path. I'll mark it correct when I get it to work! Thanks

Comment: Managed to do it by passing the navigator in the JSX, and posted that as an answer. +1 for the ideas, though...I learned a lot about globalization in js!

Comment: Glad you got it :)